# How to make logos move and scale in webflow

Tags: animation, webflow

I've got a services section in client's webflow site. It has 5 logos for each service. One of the logo is scaled more with description of the service. When a user clicks on on one of ther logos, it gets scaled and moved to the position where the highlighted logo was with new decription

I'm able to change positions of the first logo clicked however I'm having trouble moving the other logos as I've got to create a separate click interaction for every logo. Can anyone help me with this.

Please see the image for your reference.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqQ35.png)

I can create a loop where the logos change position when the is in view but I've got to create an animation with the trigger mouse clicked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

1. You can replace img scr attribute value.
2. You can resolve it by JavaScript & css combination.
3. if you want to apply animation for position of image. You may use transition & transform property of css for it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In webflow you can easily move and scale logo or any image or element by the 2D & 3D transforms options. Here you can check in the screenshot.

Thanks!

[image]